# Selenium IDE select window without href or url

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, selenium, selenium-ide

I am new in Selenium IDE. I try to select a PDF that opens during the test, but it doesn't work. I'am testing a Webapplication that is written on JSF and so includes some Java-Methodes/Classes.
I want to test if the PDF opens correctly or not. The problem is, there is no direct href in the HTML-Code. Only a Java(?)-Methode who opens the PDF. Is there any solution for this problem in Selenium IDE?

The Element you can click on is

```
<h:commandLink id="createDokument" style="background-image: none;" styleClass="Button Blue"
            action="#{myBean.checkDocument()}" value="#{buttons['BTN_Document']}">
</h:commandLink>
```

Then a javaScript function should test if a pdf can be created

IF yes the hidden button is clicked:

```
<h:commandLink id="createDocumentPdf" style="background-image: none; display: none;"
           styleClass="Button Blue"action="#{myBean.createDocument()}" value="something" target="_blank">
</h:commandLink>
```

What Firebug knows from this two buttons is:

```
<a id="mainForm:createDocumentPdf" class="Button Blue" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs

(document.getElementById('mainForm'),{'mainForm:createDocumentPdf':'mainForm:createDocumentPdf'},'_blank');}return false" 

style="background-image: none; display: none;" href="#">Something </a>

<a id="mainForm:createDocument" class="Button Blue" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs =='function'){jsfcljs

(document.getElementById('mainForm') {'mainForm:createDocument':'mainForm:createDocument'},'');return false
"style="background-image:none;" href="#" tabindex="0">Document</a>
```

I tried a few things already but nothing works....
I tried: select window | titleOfThePDFWindow
but it does not work

so all I have now is:
clickAndWait |  id=mainForm:createDocument

Comment: What on earth is that `h` element?

Comment: I honestly have no clue what the 'h' element is. I just started an
internship and my task is it to write the Selenium-Test for a
webapplication. I think it is some JavaServerFaces
notation?

I read about emulating ctrl+Tab in Selenium IDE to switch the tabs, but it doesnt seem to work